# Extended Partition using MSDOS and WIC

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-wic

I am trying to generate a wic image. Following is my requirement

- fat16-boot partition-32MB
- A 6GB extended partition which is further divided into

  - 8 logical partitions : 4 of 512MB and 4 of 1024MB each.

I am unable to generate the extended partition in correct manner. Upon using the below wks file.
I am currently getting following results

- fa16 boot partition
- 6GB ext4 partition
- 512MB of ext4 partition (seperate , expectation is it should be part of 6GB partition)
- 1GB of ext4 partition (seperate , expectation is it should be part of 6GB partition)

Following is the wks file used :

```
bootloader --ptable msdos
part /boot --size 32M --source bootimg-partition --sourceparams="file=BOOT.bin uboot.env" --ondisk sda --fstype=vfat --label boot --active --align 1024
part extended --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --size 6144M
part --ondisk mmcblk0:extended --fstype=ext4 --label cfg1 --align 1024 --size 1024M
part / --ondisk mmcblk0:extended --fstype=ext4 --label rootfs1 --align 1024 --size 512M
```